# Firebase authentication Login multiple provider with same email

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want users can login using many different provider Like Google+, Facebook and Email/Password but they will get same result if they use only same email address. Prevent multiple accounts and data managed by same UID

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a feature of Firebase Authentication. If you configure it to allow only one account per email address (which is the default I think), it will only allow a single account per email address. When a user then logs in with a different provider, you can [link the credentials for both under a single account/UID](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/account-linking).

Comment: Confusion about How to link account!!, Can you explain or any Example ?

Comment: The documentation I linked contains an example of how to link accoutns. If you're having problems making it work, edit your question to show where you are stuck.